# how do i make a movieclip move forever when an arrow key is pressed in flash actionscript 2.0? please answer

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-8

I'm working on a pac-man recreation in flash 8, using actionscript 2.0, and i need to makethe controls for pac-man, **I want him to move forever when an arrow key is pressed, just like how he does in the original pac-man,** so, can anyone give me the code for this?

I tried to find the code that makes pac-man move forever when an arrow key is pressed, but all i found is actionscript 3.0, i'm using actionscript 2.0

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, there are two ways to do it.

First, you can subscribe to the relevant events and record the state of the keys, like that:

```
var UP:Boolean = False;
var DOWN:Boolean = False;

function onKeyUp()
{
    switch (Key.getCode())
    {
        case Key.UP:
            UP = False;
            break;
        case Key.DOWN:
            DOWN = False;
            break;
    }
}

function onKeyDown()
{
    switch (Key.getCode())
    {
        case Key.UP:
            UP = True;
            break;
        case Key.DOWN:
            DOWN = True;
            break;
    }
}

Key.addListener(this);
```

Then when there's time for Pacman to act, you can check them:

```
if (UP != DOWN)
{
    if (UP)
    {
        // Do what you do to move it up.
    }
    else // if (DOWN)
    {
        // Do what you do to move it down.
    }
}
else
{
    // If they are pressed at the same time or not pressed, do nothing.
}
```

The second way is to check if the keys are pressed on spot, when it is time for Pacman to perform an action:

```
var UP:Boolean = Key.isDown(Key.UP);
var DOWN:Boolean = Key.isDown(Key.DOWN);

if (UP != DOWN)
{
    if (UP)
    {
        // Do what you do to move it up.
    }
    else // if (DOWN)
    {
        // Do what you do to move it down.
    }
}
else
{
    // If they are pressed at the same time or not pressed, do nothing.
}
```

The difference between these two is that **onKeyDown** event is generated perpetually, like if you press a key and get a line of same characters in the text editor: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa (but you cannot predict the stroke frequency and the difference between first interval and the rest, as it is controlled by the system), while **Key.isDown(...)** can be used on spot, if you meter your interactivity with timings, rather then bind it to keypress events.

Comment: thanks but, can you give me that exact code but with the parts that makes pacman move left right up and down?

Comment: @SPONGEBOBREDYTchannel That would defy the idea of **HELP**. Totally pointless, unless you figure it out for yourself.